# Completely monotone condition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality

I've stucked in this problem for a while. So I hope someones could give me suggestions.
Consider the function:
$$
f( r ) = \frac{e^{- br}}{1 + ce^{ - dr}} = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - c)^n}e^{ - (b + nd)r} 
$$ 
For given $c \in (0,\,1)$ and finite $d>0$, I want to find the condition of $b$ to make $f(.)$ is compelely monotonic function, i.e., 
$$ (-1)^l f^{(l)}(r)= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - c)^n}(b+nd)^l e^{ - (b + nd)r}  \ge 0$$
for all $l$ and $r$.

For $b = \infty$ I can show that $f(.)$ is completely monotonic.

Let denote $x_n = ( - c)^n(b+nd)^l e^{ - (b + nd)r}$, we have
$$
x_n - x_{n + 1} = ( - c)^n e^{ - (b + nd)r}(b + nd)^l\left\{ {1 + c{{\left( {1 + \frac{d}{b + nd}} \right)}^l}e^{ - dr}} \right\}
$$

Hence for fixed, positive and finite $b,\, d,\, r$ and $l$, when $n \to \infty$, $(x_n - x_{n+1}) \to 0$. So it seems that $(-1)^l f^{(l)}(r)= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty x_n$ is convergent. Those are all results I got.

Answer (score 2):

For $c\in(0,1)$ and positive $b$ and $d$, the function 
$f$   is *never* completely monotonic.

The proof uses a bit of complex function theory,  related to topics in the recent  book *Bernstein functions* by  [Schilling, Song and Vondracek](http://books.google.com/books/about/Bernstein_Functions.html?id=oiimJP52fcsC).

Suppose $f$ is completely monotonic.  By Bernstein's theorem, there is an increasing function $\mu$ on $[0,\infty)$ such that $$ f(r) = \int_0^\infty e^{-tr}\,d\mu(t), \qquad r>0. $$ Then, using Fubini's theorem, the Laplace transform of $f$ has the representation $$ F(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-sr} f(r)\,dr = \int_0^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-(s+t)r}\,dr\,d\mu(t) =  \int_0^\infty \frac{d\mu(t)}{s+t}, \quad s>0. $$ This formula defines an analytic extension of $F$ into the upper half plane $\Im s>0$  with the property that $\Im F(s)<0$ there. (Such a function is called a Stieltjes function.)

However, we can compute $F(s)$ explicitly and conclude otherwise.
 Note that by scaling $r$ we can assume $d=1$:  
$$ F(s) = \int_0^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-ce^{-r})^k e^{-(s+b)r}\,dr = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-c)^k}{s+b+k}. $$ Since $|-c|<1$ this series converges for all complex $s$ not equal to $-b-k$ for some  nonnegative integer $k$. But since $c>0$ it is not a Stieltjes function. E.g., taking  $s=-b-1+i\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$, the term for $k=1$  is $ic/\epsilon$. For  small enough $\epsilon>0$ this term dominates and yields $\Im F(-b-1+i\epsilon)>0$.  This contradicts the result from Bernstein's theorem, so $f$ cannot be completely monotonic.

(It's clear, however,  you do have complete monotonicity with $c$ of the opposite sign,  i.e., $c\in[-1,0]$. )

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I am trying to understand it.

Comment: Can you explain in more details why the formula $F(s)=  \int_0^\infty \frac{d\mu(t)}{s+t}$ defines an analytic extension of $F$ into the upper half plane $\Im s>0$  with the property that $\Im F(s)<0$ there ?

Comment: The basic idea is that for fixed $t$ and $a>0$ the function $s\mapsto a/(s+t)$ is Stieltjes, and convex combinations of Stieltjes functions are Stieltjes. More directly:
1. Note the measure $du$ is finite since $\int_0^\infty d\mu(t) = f(0)$ is finite.  Thus the integral for $F(s)$ converges absolutely if $s+t$ does not vanish for any $t\in[0,\infty)$.
2. $s\mapsto F(s)$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations by differentiating under the integral sign.

3. For $\Im s>0$,
$$\Im F(s) = \Im \int_0^\infty \frac{\bar s+t}{|s+t|^2}\,d\mu(t)
= -\Im s \int_0^\infty \frac{d\mu(t)}{|s+t|^2}<0
$$

Comment: If you choose $\Re s = -b-1$, it will not satisfies $s>0$ in the definition of $F(s)$